# Append results from MULTIPLE arrays to the INITIALLY GENERATED ul after click, how can this be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So, I have a bunch of sources for Autocomplete, like this:

```
var search1 = [{
    search: "authors1"
}, {
    search: "autocomplete1"
}, {
    search: "automatic1"
}];
var search2 = [{
    search: "authors2"
}, {
    search: "autocomplete2"
}, {
    search: "automatic2"
}];
var search3 = [{
    search: "authors3"
}, {
    search: "autocomplete3"
}, {
    search: "automatic3"
}];
```

**I MUST** store data in different arrays, so please don't suggest me to join them.
HTML:

```
<input data-source="search1,search2,search3" type="text" value="" />
<div id="loadingmsg" style="display:none">Searching...</div>
```

I'd like to have a **recursive** function that will come through all the sources specified in "data-source" attribute and append results to one menu. For example, when I type "auth", I want to see this:

1. `#loadingmsg` reveals itself.
2. The resulting menu (containing "authors1", "authors2" and "authors3") shows up.
3. `#loadingmsg` disappears.
   Is it possible?

Comment: You will probably get a lot more helpful answers if you can prune down your code to only the most relevant parts

Comment: Please, see the revised version

Comment: Is there any ajax or other asynchronous code? I don't see a use case for the #loadingmsg currently

Comment: ajax - maybe yes, maybe not, it doesn't matter. In any case, I require it to appear when the process starts (the recursive function must hide it when completed)

Comment: Is it possible for search1, search2, etc. to be array indices of one variable rather than each variables themselves?

Comment: @Explosion Pills: Well, yes, if you mean search[i], the recursion must add them one by one... **EDIT** Oh, stop. It must not forget to remove the previous one

Answer (score 0):

With `<input data-source="1,2,3" />`

```
//bind a response to typing for each of these inputs
$("img[data-source]").on('keyup', function () {

   //get typed value
   var value = $(this).val();

   //clear the current menu
   $("#menu").empty();

   //show loading image (probably ineffective)
   $("#loadingimg").show();

   //iterate over source keys acquired from <input> data
   $.each($(this).data('source').split(','), function () {

      //iterate over corresponding object in `search`
      $.each(search[this], function () {

         //typed value matches string
         if (this.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            $("#menu").append('<span>' + this + '</span>');
         }
      });
   });
   $("#loadingimg").hide();
});
```

Comment: What menu do you mean? I'm talking about [jquery ui autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) results (search1, search2 and search3 are for its `source` option)

Comment: @lyricallywicked then instead of appending to menu, just add them to the source option I suppose